# How to select records only if joined table has a count greater than 10?

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to select the `memberid` where count of `logins` is greater than 10

I wrote this query:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(member.member_id))
FROM member
LEFT JOIN location_member ON (member.member_id = location_member.member_id)
WHERE Month(FROM_UNIXTIME(member.r_date)) = 11
   AND Year(FROM_UNIXTIME(member.r_date)) = 2011
   AND FROM_UNIXTIME(member.r_date, '%d') = 28
   AND member.pc_address_validated <> 1
   **OR (if checkins > 10)**
```

How can I check if the count is more than 10?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
SELECT memberId
FROM checkin
GROUP BY memberId
HAVING COUNT(1) > 3
```

To address your new query:

```
SELECT member.member_id
FROM member
INNER JOIN checkins ON member.member_id = checkins.member_id
LEFT JOIN location_member ON (member.member_id = location_member.member_id)
WHERE Month(FROM_UNIXTIME(member.r_date)) = 11
   AND Year(FROM_UNIXTIME(member.r_date)) = 2011
   AND FROM_UNIXTIME(member.r_date, '%d') = 28
   AND member.pc_address_validated <> 1
GROUP BY member.member_id
HAVING COUNT(1) > 10
```

Comment: Thanks adam.. I think I will have to use the two tables because it is even more complex..

Comment: With no need for any join, let alone a LEFT JOIN.  That would be relevant if condition was 'less than three logins' but not for 'more than three logins'.

Comment: @Prashant Could you update your question to reflect the additional complexity?  This may allow for answers closer to what you are doing.

Comment: @Prashant I have updated my answer to address your larger query.

Comment: @Adam: it returns me with lots of 1's but not one no. (total count)

Comment: @Prashant Sorry, I didn't notice that the `COUNT` was still in the select.  Please try now.

Comment: @Adam: I need to count them as well.. also is there a way to put this as OR statement? because I wanna count if pc_address is != 1 or if checkins is > 10

Comment: @Adam: the reason is because until the time pc_address is not equal to one, checkins cannot be equal to 1 as well.. so.. it is important to have this subquery in or clause.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5545/discussion-between-prashant-and-adam-wenger)

Comment: Agree. Only a small note: when you are grouping on some column and pulling only that column, there's no need to additionally apply DISTINCT to the output.

Comment: @AndriyM Good catch on the `DISTINCT`, thanks.  I didn't remove it when I brought the OP query down into my answer to modify.

Comment: I guess two queries are required to count! Thanks Adam!

Answer (score 0):

Your query will be similar to this,

```
select ck.memberId,ck.login from Member m join
CheckIn ck on m.id = ck.memberId
group by ck.memberId, ck.login having count(ck.login) > 3
```